# Tkinter - change location of treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I use tkinter for an assigment with a treeview:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("one", width=100 )
tree.column("two", width=100)
tree.column("three", width=120)
tree.heading("one", text="3")
tree.heading("two", text="2")
tree.heading("three", text="1")
tree.place(x=0,y=0)
```

then it places it at the top left corner where it should be.

But whenever I start writing using this

```
tree.insert("", 0, values=(1, 2, 3))
```

it goes to a y axes of 0 and a x axes that is in the middle of screen.

Is there any way to fix it so that it stays on the top left corner?

Comment: Running your code the `treeview` widget stays in the top left corner. Can you please provide a working example which demonstrates the problem following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't duplicate it either. Please provide a [mcve] that lets us duplicate the problem.

Comment: i fixed it already the problem was that i used tree.pack() and for some reason that changed that it goes to the middle. 
one more question right now i have this
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/o10dxh/9 you see a lot of empty spaces in the left. how can i remove that? you cant really see it in the picture but it is to the left of woeren a lot of white space

Comment: @Tijdjes123 Please raise a new post if you have another question.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the query you had in the comments above.

`.pack()` differs from `.place()` when it comes to positioning of the widgets. For a start `.pack()`'s default position for displaying widgets is the top, middle of it's parent if it is the first widget to be default packed in the parent, else it's the middle of the bottom edge of the last widget to be default packed in the parent. Where calling `.place()` without any attributes will not actually draw the widget visibly on the screen, instead you **must** clarify a position for the widget (there are several sets of attributes which can be used for this with `.place()`).

This is why using `.pack()` on the widget instead of `.place()` caused it to move to the top middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any others out there that are having troubles when you write `.place` and it just stays in the same location, it might be because later on in the code you have another `.place` referring to the same object that overrides the original placement. Just do a `control + f` and type in `object_name.place(` and see if any other lines appear.